# How to Find ElementName of Parent View (XAML) in TargetObject of ChangePropertyAction WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatrigger, interaction

I'm having DataGrid, the Grid has a Filter Functioning. The Filter Icon Button is styled as DataGridColumnHeader in app.xaml and I attached the style to my DataGrid. If the Button gets Click, then it opens a Filter Popup to perform Filter. The Popup is designed in a Parent View XAML.

The DataGrid View XAML inherits the Parent View XAML. Now I need to set the ElementName=autoFilter in Popup or ElementName=popFilter in Filter Icon Button. I Can't able to call the control using TargetObject of ChangePropertyAction in WPF. Kindly assist.

The DataGrid View: gridView.xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="EmpList" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource FilterDataGridColumnHeader}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpList}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Employee Name" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridElementStyle}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Employee Age" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridElementStyle}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Parent View Contains Popup: MainView.xaml

```
<Popup Name="popFilter" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="False" Width="200" IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupFilterOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Opened">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=autofilter}" PropertyName="Visibility"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=autofilter}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
        <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,15">
            <TextBlock Text="Welcome to Popup Window" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Filter Icon Button in ColumnHeaderStyle : app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="FilterDataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=autofilter}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=autofilter}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=popFilter}" PropertyName="IsOpen">
                                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>True</ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>

                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="autofilter" Visibility="Collapsed" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FilterButtonStyleKey}"  Margin="0 0 3 0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

The Icon Button Image Key: FilterButtonStyleKey

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FilterButtonStyleKey">
    <Canvas Height="15.898" Width="15.297" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
        <Path Data="M16.0117,6.7368C18.3417,6.7368,20.6727,6.7358,23.0027,6.7378C23.5327,6.7378,23.5977,6.8308,23.6437,7.3438C23.7027,7.9958,23.4897,8.4748,23.0197,8.9548C21.4107,10.5968,19.8547,12.2888,18.2957,13.9788C18.1647,14.1208,18.1137,14.3828,18.1117,14.5898C18.0987,17.0608,18.1067,19.5308,18.0907,22.0018C18.0887,22.2158,18.0077,22.4968,17.8607,22.6158C17.7697,22.6878,17.4587,22.5408,17.2807,22.4368C16.3057,21.8718,15.3447,21.2788,14.3677,20.7148C14.0637,20.5408,13.9287,20.3278,13.9297,19.9728C13.9407,18.1778,13.9257,16.3848,13.9357,14.5908C13.9367,14.2698,13.8367,14.0388,13.6137,13.8058C12.1347,12.2548,10.6717,10.6898,9.2027,9.1298C9.0967,9.0168,8.9927,8.9018,8.8797,8.7958C8.4137,8.3608,8.2387,7.6118,8.4377,7.0158C8.5277,6.7478,8.7137,6.7358,8.9347,6.7368C10.0937,6.7388,11.2517,6.7378,12.4097,6.7378C13.6107,6.7378,14.8107,6.7378,16.0117,6.7368z" Height="16.898" Canvas.Left="-0.5" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Stroke="#FF323232" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Canvas.Top="-0.5" Width="16.297"/>
        <Path Data="M14.2427,14.3921L17.9117,14.3921" Height="1" Canvas.Left="5.386" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Stroke="#FF323232" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Canvas.Top="7.156" Width="4.669"/>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

I need to show (Visibility:Visible) the Filter Icon Button while on Mouse Hover Event of the Corresponding Column or If user can click the Filter Icon Button then the Filter Popup gets opened and that time the Icon should show - Filter Popup IsOpen=True state. The Filter Icon Button should Collapsed while on Popup gets closed while on Icon Button Clicked otherwise Mouse Hover is not happened.

> Note:
>
> Design the Datagrid in one XAML and the Filter Popup should be in Main
>   View XAML, The DataGrid XAML inherits the Main View XAML.
>
> The Filter Icon is a Button designed in app.xaml and call the Style in
>   the DataGrid.